# Plotting 2 graphs together in Rickshaw

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rickshaw

Is there a way to plot 2 graphs together with different Y axes?

I have some data (page views, stacked area by referrer) which I'd like to plot with an overlayed line graph of number of actions over time.

I already have both graphs separately, but just wondering if there's a way to combine them into 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to draw both graphs by passing in the element you're outputting to as the target for each.  Are you using SVG for output?  Can you post some of the code you're working with?

Comment: Hey sorry for the delayed reply... I tried to work with plunker for a while to get it to display my data but I can't get it to work... it works fine with my own data though.. here's what I have so far http://plnkr.co/edit/kX4s0eCE2Vofvou1hkf2

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

Here's the [simplest of examples](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bvi5H1CqbWWwRhGFzWy1?p=preview).

```
var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
  element: document.getElementById("chart"),
  renderer: 'multi',
  series: [{
    name: 'one',
    data: [{
      x: 0,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 2,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 3,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 4,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 5,
      y: Math.random()
    }],
    color: 'blue',
    renderer: 'stack'
  }, {
    name: 'two',
    data: [{
      x: 0,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 2,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 3,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 4,
      y: Math.random()
    }, {
      x: 5,
      y: Math.random()
    }],
    renderer: 'line',
    color: 'red'
  }]
});

graph.render();
```

Comment: Thanks! that's really close to what I'm looking for!

Unfortunately, the scales are very different (sometimes the line plot is very hard to see) and I'm more concerned with the relationship of the trends. Is there a way to plot just one of the series in a different Y axis?